# Server returned HTTP response code: 401

Tags: java

I am new in java, and trying to connect to an application but I am receiving error - Server returned HTTP response code: 401--

I followed all the help urls mentioned and tried almost all connection code on topic but still I am not able to connect to url through mentioned credentials.

Code as follows-

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.DataOutputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
 import java.net.URL;
 import sun.misc.*;

 import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
 import org.apache.commons.codec.*;

 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
 public class hello {

/**
 * @param args
 */
//private final String USER_AGENT = "";
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    hello http = new hello();


    System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http GET request");
    http.sendGet();

   // System.out.println("\nTesting 2 - Send Http POST request");
  //  http.sendPost();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void sendGet() throws Exception {

    String url = "https:/***.com/";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    String userPassword= "gangajap:Mumbai02";

    String encoding = new String(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils.getBytesUtf8(userPassword)));
    System.out.println("----"+encoding);


    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    con.setRequestProperty("charset", "UTF-8");
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic" +encoding);


    String urlParameters = "?USER=gangajap&MRP=15c6ca083c2f75a73e0fbbd2832290f29&PROJECTID=1&USECACHEURL=1&IGNORE_REAL_ACTIVE_TIME=1";

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("1111" +wr);
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());

}

 }
```

Comment: Missing space after `basic` here: `"Basic" +encoding`

Comment: aren't you missing a space here ` con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic" +encoding);` ? - before the encoded user/pass

Comment: Can't you use HttpClient here? are you able to hit this url using postman or any rest client  to ensure all the credentials and url is right?

Comment: Thanks for contributing to my question and helping me out but I realized after connecting it by Rest Client that with username:password even domain name was required. So I passed domain name along with username and 401 was gone.

Comment: @Raz Without adding the whitespace?...

Comment: No the syntax mentioned seems to be mandatory, I was doing it wrong but adding a whitespace worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing space in

`con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic" +encoding);`

should be

`con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " +encoding);`

because `encoded` is a string of base64 chars and according to the [Authorization header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication) it must be separated from `Basic` (the auth type) with a space

Answer (score 0):

your HTTP Basic Authentication header missing a whitespace, and you can see more details from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24191_01/common/tutorials/authn_http_basic.html):

```
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic" +encoding);
                                              ^
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " +encoding);
```